# Issues loading .json file from file on Android

Tags: java, android, json, file, uri

first I thank you all if you can help me.

In my project, I have to upload a file .json in my application and I take it from a browser.

I handle it from the **Manifest.xml** with an Intent Filter as follow:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file"  android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.json" android:mimeType="*/*"  />
    </intent-filter>
```

Then, from the MainActivity.java, I construct the File object and get the String result from the File created:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        if (action != null){
            if (action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) == 0) {
                String scheme = intent.getScheme();
                String path = intent.getDataString();                 

                if (scheme.compareTo(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE) == 0) {

                    try {
                        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        System.out.println("InputStream loaded");
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("InputStream not loaded");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The value of the String object **path** is **file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/prova.json**.

The main problem is that, when I try to load the file, it throws an exception saying that the file doesn't exist, even if it's really sure it is.

Thank you all again!

Comment: Post the stack trace, always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the json you want to read is on the device storage so in your manifest you need to enable the following permissions

this will enable tour app to read files on the device outside of the aplication context

Comment: When I've added the permission, the code starts to work! Thank you!